After submitting a form, page becomes blank (white)
I have a simple HTML page that contains a form with these fields: Full Name, Email, Phone and Text area.
Full Name & Email are mandatory fields.
When I click the 'Send' button, the page becomes white, and nothing was sent.
I have an HTML page with the form, Javascript to validate the fields, and a PHP file to send the form to an email address.
What am I missing?
HTML & JS

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sendForm.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-container">
        <form id="contactForm" action="send_email.php" method="post">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-footer">
                <span id="formMessage" class="form-message"></span>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contactForm').on('submit', function(event) {
            let isValid = true;
            const fullName = $('#fullName').val().trim();
            const email = $('#email').val().trim();
            const formMessage = $('#formMessage');

            // Reset previous error styles and message
            $('#fullName').removeClass('error');
            $('#email').removeClass('error');
            formMessage.text('');

            // Validate Full Name
            if (!fullName) {
                $('#fullName').addClass('error');
                isValid = false;
            }

            // Validate Email
            if (!email) {
                $('#email').addClass('error');
                isValid = false;
            }

            if (!isValid) {
                formMessage.text('Mandatory fields');
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


PHP
<?php
// Enable error reporting for debugging
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $fullName = trim($_POST['fullName']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);

    $errors = [];

    // Validate Full Name
    if (empty($fullName)) {
        $errors[] = 'Full name is required';
    }

    // Validate Email
    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors[] = 'Email is required';
    } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = 'Invalid email format';
    }

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        $errorString = implode(', ', $errors);
        echo "<script>
                window.onload = function() {
                    var formMessage = document.getElementById('formMessage');
                    if (formMessage) {
                        formMessage.textContent = 'Mandatory fields: $errorString';
                        if ('$fullName' === '') {
                            document.getElementById('fullName').classList.add('error');
                        }
                        if ('$email' === '') {
                            document.getElementById('email').classList.add('error');
                        }
                    }
                }
              </script>";
    } else {
        $to = "123@domain.com";
        $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
        $body = "Full Name: $fullName\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nMessage: $message";
        $headers = "From: $email";

        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
            echo "<script>
                    window.onload = function() {
                        var formMessage = document.getElementById('formMessage');
                        if (formMessage) {
                            formMessage.textContent = 'Details sent';
                        }
                    }
                  </script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>
                    window.onload = function() {
                        var formMessage = document.getElementById('formMessage');
                        if (formMessage) {
                            formMessage.textContent = 'Error sending details';
                        }
                    }
                  </script>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid request method";
}
?>


A form which should send details to an email, but the page gets blank after submitting.

After submission you're redirected to where the form points to. Which doesn't seem to have any visible HTML content. Either don't redirect or include some content at the destination page.

Just to add to what @VLAZ said, the action attributes in your form gets triggered after the validation is done. You can trigger a redirect from your php code back to the form or handle the form submission asynchronously, by removing the action attribute on the form and use ajax to send.

Thank you guys, I want the user to stay on the page of the form, and a message 'Details sent' will be shown next to the 'send' button when sending, I already designed this to work like that, only have this problem and I will be happy for an example how to solve this, what should I change? I'm more into design and using the GPT for coding :)

Almost forgot, the details are not sent to the targeted email

If you want the user to stay on the same page you will need to learn how to submit the form data via AJAX. There a gazillion tutorials online about that kind of thing. N.B. note that chatGPT is a chatbot, not a programmmer. It just puts togeher text in the sequence it thinks is most likely to make sense. It's quite good at that, to be fair, but programming often requires fine detail and subtle understanding of the situation. For that, such an LLM is not quite accurate enough, it will make mistakes,and sometimes it will also regurgitate awful code it finds online, without knowing better.

Anyway, what your code actually returns right now is simply the block of JavaScript your PHP script echoes in echo 'window.onload = function().... Of course, that code doesn't do anything when the browser receives it, because there is no formMessage element on the page - the page consists of the <script> block and nothing else.

(I discovered this by using the browser's tools to look for it. You can use the Network tool in your browser's Developer Tools to analyse what the PHP script actually returned - load your form, open the Network tool, enable "preserve log" in the Network tool, then complete and submit the form. You will see the request to send_email.php appear in the Network tool's log. Click on it, and click on the Response tab within that - there you will see everything that PHP returned. That is now your new web page. The page which held the form is gone.)

Does anyone know about a tutorial for a simple form or a free plugin which works with HTML and validate inputs? Thank you agains

@VadimL html5 has a lot of validation tools built in, for client-side validation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation . That doesn't remove the need for you to have server-side validation as well (since any client side validation mechanism can easily be bypassed by someone who knows what they're doing)
